# Android Color Picker Transparent Issue

Tags: android, transparent, color-picker

I am trying to add Colors from Color Picker in Notes and it works Great.. But if no Color is selected from the Color Picker, it directly applies Transparent Color to the Note.. making the note unable to see. Like the image given below(Notes Image Link).

[image]

Code:

```
private void setColor() {
    colorcalendar = ColorPickerDialog.newInstance(
            R.string.color_picker_default_title,
            colorChoice(this),
            selectedColor,
            5,
            isTablet(this)? ColorPickerDialog.SIZE_LARGE : ColorPickerDialog.SIZE_XSMALL);
        colorcalendar.setOnColorSelectedListener(new ColorPickerSwatch.OnColorSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onColorSelected(int color) {
            selectedColor = color;
        }
    });
    i = colorcalendar.getSelectedColor();
    colorcalendar.show(getFragmentManager(), "cal");
}

public static int[] colorChoice(Context context){

    int[] mColorChoices=null;
    String[] color_array = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.default_color_choice_values);

    if (color_array!=null && color_array.length>0) {
        mColorChoices = new int[color_array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < color_array.length; i++) {
            mColorChoices[i] = Color.parseColor(color_array[i]);
        }
    }
    return mColorChoices;
}
```

Is there any option to set default Color if no Color is selected by User from the Color Picker?

Comment: in your color choice method there is a if statement, which runs when colors are selected. after if write an else statement and define your default color there. I guess it should work

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize selectedColor  variable with any color.

Comment: Please click up arrow beside answer (upvote) if it solved the issue.

Comment: When I select Color and then go back and again open that color picker activity, then some other color is seleted.

Answer (score 0):

how about check whether the color is transparent or not in ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener like this:

```
@Override
public void colorChanged(int color) {
    if (color == Color.TRANSPARENT)
        // set default color
        mColor = Color.BLUE;
    else mColor = color;
}
```

this may help: http://android.okhelp.cz/color-picker-dialog-android-example/